# ¿Cómo centro correctamente un botón?

Tags: python, tkinter, label

Estoy haciendo un programa en python que va de descargar videos de youtube porque estoy aprendiendo a usar una librería grafica `tkinter` El caso es que hice un botón pero no puedo centrarlo, queda un poco mas a la izquierda, este es el código

```
import tkinter

ventana = tkinter.Tk()
ventana.geometry("600x600")

titulo = tkinter.Label(ventana)
titulo2 = tkinter.Label(ventana)

boton = tkinter.Button(ventana)

titulo.config(text="Descargar videos de youtube", anchor="center", font=("Arial",25))
titulo2.config(text="Ingresar URL a continuacion", anchor="center", font=("Arial",10))
boton.config(text="descargar")

urlInput = tkinter.Entry(ventana)

url = urlInput.get()

titulo.pack()
titulo2.pack()
urlInput.pack()
boton.place(relx=0.45,rely=0.5,width=100,anchor='w')
ventana.mainloop()
```

[image: y esto es lo que pasa con el botón "descargar"]

Comment: Buen día, haz hecho una buena primera pregunta al incluir tu código y el problema de forma específica, aún así, permíteme recomendarte hacer el [recorrido de bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leer la sección [¿Cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). También hay que repasar [izquierda y derecha](https://www.smartick.es/blog/matematicas/geometria/izquierda-y-derecha/#:~:text=En%20este%20caso%20depende%20de,lados%20derecho%20e%20izquierdo%20coinciden.) haha, saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Buen día,

Para centrarlo de forma horizontal podrías utilizar

```
boton.pack(side='top')
```

O también `anchor='c'` en lugar de `'w'` junto con `relx=0.5`

```
boton.place(relx=0.5,rely=0.5,width=100,anchor='c')
```

Ejemplo completo:

```
import tkinter

ventana = tkinter.Tk()
ventana.geometry("600x600")

titulo = tkinter.Label(ventana)
titulo2 = tkinter.Label(ventana)

boton = tkinter.Button(ventana)


titulo.config(text="Descargar videos de youtube", anchor="center", font=("Arial",25))
titulo2.config(text="Ingresar URL a continuacion", anchor="center", font=("Arial",10))
boton.config(text="descargar")

urlInput = tkinter.Entry(ventana)

url = urlInput.get()

titulo.pack()
titulo2.pack()
urlInput.pack()
boton.place(relx=0.5,rely=0.5,width=100,anchor='c')
ventana.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

resolví el problema, solo que acomodé un poco el código a mi gusto

```
import tkinter

ventana = tkinter.Tk()
ventana.geometry("600x300")

titulo = tkinter.Label(ventana,text="Descargar videos de youtube", font=("Arial",25))
titulo.pack(side="top")

titulo2 = tkinter.Label(ventana,text="Ingresar URL a continuacion", font=("Arial",10))
titulo2.pack(side="top")

urlInput = tkinter.Entry(ventana)
urlInput.pack()
url = urlInput.get()

boton = tkinter.Button(ventana,text="Descargar")
boton.pack(side="top")

ventana.mainloop()
```

Espero que te sirva, moví las cosas que tenias en .config(), ya que eso se puede poner en la definición del botón, espero que te ayude.